# $f:X\to Y$ epimorphism of module $X$ onto $Y$. Prove that for every homomorphism $h:F\to Y$ of free module $F$ into $Y$, there exists $g$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $f:X\to Y$ denote an arbitrary epimorphism of a module $X$ over
>   $R$ onto a module $Y$ over $R$. Prove that, for every homomorphism
>   $h:F\to Y$ of a free module $F$ over $R$ into the module $Y$, there
>   exists a homomorphism $g:F\to X$ satisfying $f\circ g = h$

What did the exercise mean for a homomorphism of a free module $F$ over $R$ into a module $Y$? Is the set of the free module $Y$? If so, this is the diagram:

Y ---f'---- F

\
  g'

```
 \
   X
```

right? Because $F$ is a free module, for every $g':Y\to X$, there exists $h':F\to X$ such that $g' = h'\circ f'$.

The exercise is asking me to prove that for every homomorphism $h:F\to Y$, there exists $g:F\to X$ satisfying $f\circ g = h$, right? Isn't that the same as proving that $Y$ is a free module over $X$? If so, how should I prove it? I think it has to do with using inverses of the already existing homomorphisms and compositions, but for inverses, injectivity is requires, so I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a basis for the free module $F$. $h$ is determined by the basis elements $s\in S$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = h(s)$. Define $g(s) = x$ on the basis $S$ and extend by linearity to $F$. Since $h = fg$ on $S$, it must be same on all of $F$.